# Count array elements based on criterias PHP

Tags: php

Looking for help in counting elements in a php array meeting certain criteria and getting them to properly display in html table.

I have this array named $Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fMonth] => 12
            [fSnowDepth] => 0.2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fMonth] => 12
            [fSnowDepth] => 3.7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fMonth] => 12
            [fSnowDepth] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fMonth] => 01
            [fSnowDepth] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [fMonth] => 01
            [fSnowDepth] => 0.5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [fMonth] => 01
            [fSnowDepth] => 4.5
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [fMonth] => 01
            [fSnowDepth] => 1.3
        )

)
```

What I'm trying to do is count the months which meet conditions such as fSnowDepth >= 1 and < 3, fSnowDepth >= 3 and < 5, etc. and place in html table. **I'm expecting this** with (blank) for the months with no count:

```
               | Jan  | Feb  | Mar  | Apr  | May  | Jun  | Jul  | Aug  | Sep  | Oct  | Nov  | Dec
SD >=1 and < 3 |  2   |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |  1
SD >=3 and < 5 |  1   |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |  1
... etc depths |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
```

The code I have is:

```
$array = $result['rawSumSnowDepth'];

foreach ($array as $key => $items) {
    if ($items['fSnowDepth'] >= 1 && $items['fSnowDepth'] < 3) {
        $value          = $items['fMonth'];
        $output[$value] = ($output[$value] ?? 0) + 1;

            for ($x = 0; $x <= 11; $x++) {
                if ($x + 1 == $items['fMonth']) {
                    $result['snDaysOverAmt'][$x] = array($output[$value]);
                } elseif (empty($result['snDaysOverAmt'][$x])) {
                    $result['snDaysOverAmt'][$x] = array($output[$value] => "&nbsp;");
                }
            }
        }
    }

if (isset($result['snDaysOverAmt'])) {
    foreach ($result['snDaysOverAmt'] as $amounts => $amount) {
        if ($amount) {
            echo '<td>' . implode($amount) . '</td>';
        }
    }
}
```

This code works like a charm for the first row of snow depths >= 1 and < 3 but when I run the code again for the next row (>= 3 and < 5) and I get what appears to be a doubling of the first row.

Is there another way to do this so I can include different snow depth counts **AND** is there a more concise way of doing this? I'm still a PHP rookie so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have `if (isset($array))` inside the loop? How could you be looping over the array if it's not set?

Comment: @Barmar - I've tried many various ways involving cutting and pasting and probably added code not necessary. Thanks

Comment: Did you empty the `$output` array between the runs? If not, you're adding the counts for 3-5 to the existing counts for 1-3.

Comment: [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @Barmar By using unset($output)? When I did this I get the same results as the previous row. Thanks

Comment: @Barmar - thank you for your help. I wasn't quite sure how to do this but I ended up having to use $output = [ ];  and $result['snDaysOverAmt'] = [ ]; and I'm getting results I expected. Still wonder if there is another way to have this code more compact with the same results. Thanks again, Barmar!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar this was all that was needed:

$output                  = [];

$result['snDaysOverAmt'] = [];

these were placed after the last closing bracket in the code provided in the question above.